# Illegal assembly instructions on android: VLD2

Tags: android, assembly, android-ndk, arm, android-ndk-r5

I am trying to use an assembly optimized version of a third party library in an android application. Everything compiles and links fine, but I am crashing on a specific assembly instruction : vld2.8  {d8,d10}, [r6, :128]!
From what I've read, this instruction should be compatible with the device I'm using (Galaxy Tab 10.1), but I receive a SIGILL signal: Illegal instruction.

Anyone has encounter this before?

Jean-Simon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Galaxy Tab 10.1 has Tegra2 CPU which has no NEON unit. So assembly code you are trying is not compatible with your device. (`vld2.8` is one of NEON SIMD instructions).

Comment: Thanks. That was it.
I ran cpuFeature() and indeed, it is not supported.